# Hive configuration is not reflected

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, apache-tez

I am using hive-site.xml to change some of the configuration parameters. for ex.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>tez</value>
</property>
```

But when I connect to the hive server using beeline with the following command -

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

It does not retain the server configuration. i.e when i run any query, it always used a MR job, however i configured the engine to be tez. But with in beeline if i do

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

It uses tez. Why is it that despite setting this in hite-site.xml, the config is not reflected. Or the beeline overrides all the config?

Comment: What version of tez are you using?

Comment: @karma4917 Hey, it was my mistake, it did not realize that there were multiple instances running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple instances of hive server running and since my beeline is connecting to the one which did not read the updated configuration. Once I kill all the instances and start only one, I could see that the configuration got picked.